# How to convert an alpha numeric string into long by java code?

Tags: java, type-conversion

Eg. BRYR904000Z5  must be converted into numeric format such that 
( A = 101, B=102, C=103.... you get it till Z=126 )

I want BRYR904000Z5  as 1021181251189040001265
I would also want to know if the entire number can be displayed. (working on a password generator)

I saw a code to separate the characters but this difficult to understand for me. Thank you

Comment: You need a loop on the characters of the string, to build a new one. It's far from being difficult. Try something.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a skeleton of an algorithm:

- create a new, empty StringBuilder
- loop through all the chars of the string
- at each iteration:

  - if the current char is >= 'A' and <= 'Z', transform it to its numeric value, and append this numeric value to the StringBuilder
  - else, append the current character to the StringBuilder
- transform the StringBuilder into a String

Answer (score 1):

If we're dealing with all capital letters, as it seems that we are, the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value for `A` is 65.  So, in order to get `A` to be 101, we have to add 36:

```
/*Expects only capital letters*/
public int charToIntCustomConversion(char c)
{
    return  (int) c + 36;
}
```

`(int) c` gets the ASCII value for `c` and returns that `int` + 36.

To convert back:

```
/*Expects only capital letters*/
public char intToCharCustomConversion(int n)
{
    return  (char) (n - 36);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Forgive me if there is any confusion, the above methods are only for converting from `char` to `int` and `int` to `char`.  You don't need to convert the numbers, since they remain the same, ie simply add them to the `String`.

In other words, loop through your `String` and call `charToIntCustomConversion` when you encounter a letter (again, assumed all are capital), if you encounter a number, simply add it to converted string.

Going back to the original `String` is a little trickier, but that does not seem to be what you are asking, nonetheless, if you know that an `int` cooresponds to a character that was converted, you can use `intToCharCustomConversion`.

**Converting Back:**
If you want to easily be able to determine if a number in the *converted* `String` cooresponds to a character or a number from the original `String`, the easiest thing to do will probably be to use an Array.  If an element in the *converted* array is a single number, you know that it was originally a number.  If it is a 3-digit number, you know that it was originally a `char`.

NB:
 There are many more, potentially better ways to do this..

Comment: This will break where numbers occur in the input string.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen "Expects only capital letters."

Comment: @HunterMcMillen and/or downvoter, see edit.  No idea why I'm getting downvotes.  I provided a way to make the necessary conversion.  The numbers do not need to be put through the methods, since they remain constant...

Comment: you right that was stupid mistake from me )-: I changed my post.

Comment: SteveP: I believe this is valid, countered apparently irrational downvote.

Comment: @hexafraction I'm not sure what you mean, exactly.  If you're saying that you countered the seeming irrational downvote with an upvote, then thank you. :)

Comment: @SteveP. Yes, indeed. Pardon ambiguous grammar.

Comment: Initially you posted a way to convert between capital letters and to the numbering scheme above, but posted no explanation about how to handle digits, and thus did *not* solve the problem. That is why I downvoted, I'll remove it now since you have added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
     char c = string.charAt(i);
     if (Character.isLetter(c) {
         result.append(c - 0x0041 + 101);
     } else if (Character.isDigit) {
         result.append(c);
     } else throw new RuntimeException("BS");
 }
```

0x0041 stands for the unicode of the uppercase A.